# Angular Form using Global input and button component and submit values

Tags: angular, typescript, io, angular-directive

this is my login-component.html

```html
<div class="form-feild">
  <label [ngClass]="focused ? 'label-focused' : ''">{{label}}</label>
  <input [type]="type" (focus)="focused = true" (blur)="onBlur($event)" >
</div>
```

and my login-component.ts

```html
import { Component, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
})
export class InputComponent  {
  @Input() label : string;
  @Input() type : string; 
  @Input() name:string


  focused : boolean


  onBlur(event:any){
    const value = event.target.value
    if(!value){
      this.focused = false
    }
  }

}
```

I have made input as global component and same the button as global component. and I'm using this component on my login page the code for login page 
login.ts

```html
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

focused: boolean

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onBlur(event:any){
    const value = event.target.value

    if(!value){
      this.focused = false
    }
  }

  

}
```

and Login.html is :

```html
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <h3>Sign in to continue</h3>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()"> 
    <app-input label="Email Id" type="text" ></app-input>
    <app-input label="Password" type="password" ></app-input>
    <a routerLink="#" class="forget-password">Forget Password?</a>
    <app-button label="Login" ></app-button>
    <app-icon-button icon="" src="../../../assets/img/svg/Google__G__Logo.svg" label="Connect using Google">
    </app-icon-button>
  </form>
  <p class="footer-text">I'm new user <a routerLink="/register">Sign Up</a></p>
</ion-content>
```

and I have achieved this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQDqA.png)

**Now my problem is to take the values from the inputs on login page and use it but I'm beginner so don't getting and idea how to get the values and use it for login . Please anyone can tell me how to do this.**

Comment: Inside your component, you can add an `@output` decorator and from your login page, you can add callbacks and subscribe to the values of each component, search for @ouput decorator usage... second choice, in case you will always use your elements inside a form, then you could add a form control name to the fields you need to fetch there values and on submission, you can just get the form values through this.loginForm.value which will return an object will all form properties and values inside it

Comment: @MostafaHarb I have tried to add formControl inside formgroup in login page and pass form control name in <app-input [formControl] > and defiend on input component also , but it is giving error that formGroup error on input component page that formControl only can added inside formGroup But how I make formGroup on input component.  Can you show me how to do this ?

Comment: in login page, did u have [formGroup]="loginForm" added or it was removed when u tested?

Comment: @MostafaHarb I have removed it after testing

Comment: well, try a third approach, which is decalring the variables in login page and bind the variables in the component to these variables, example in login page you add in the ts class variable named email, and you pass this variable to the component with input decorator, [inputValue]="email" and inside your component `@input('inputValue') inputValue : any;` and html part  <input [value]="inputValue" [type]="type" (focus)="focused = true" (blur)="onBlur($event)" >, i think this approach should work as well

Comment: @MostafaHarb I think It is not working for me Can you do the code for me ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you basically want to create custom form controls and bind them to your original form. To do this you will have to use the `ControlValueAccessor` and `Validator` interfaces.

Here is a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-form-controls-demo) of something similar to what you're trying to do. Focus on the `required-field` component and how this is used inside the main form.

You can read a detailed explanation of how all this works in [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-custom-form-controls-nested-form-groups-made-easy-2ac09e91cf67).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you have added a form group on the form element but it is not initialized in your component file, I am assuming you have setup reactive forms,

you can create a form group in your LoginPage component

```
loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', []),
    password: new FormControl('', []),
  })
```

add a new input decorator in your InputComponent to get a form control

```
@Input() control:FormControl
```

add the control to the input field in login-component.html

```
<div class="form-feild">
  <label [ngClass]="focused ? 'label-focused' : ''">{{label}}</label>
  <input [type]="type" (focus)="focused = true" (blur)="onBlur($event)" [formControl]="control">
</div>
```

once you have set up the Input Component, you need to bind the email and password form controls to the app-input element in login.htm

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()"> 

    <app-input label="Email Id" type="text"[control]="loginForm.get('email')"></app-input>
    <app-input label="Password" type="password" [control]="loginForm.get('password')"></app-input>

    <a routerLink="#" class="forget-password">Forget Password?</a>
    <app-button label="Login" ></app-button>
    <app-icon-button icon="" src="../../../assets/img/svg/Google__G__Logo.svg" label="Connect using Google">
    </app-icon-button>
  </form>
```

now that your inputs are linked to a form control you can subscribe to valuechanges to get the text entered in the input fields

This is how your login page component should look like with all the above changes

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', []),
    password: new FormControl('', []),
  })

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(email => {
      // Do what you want with the email entered in the input field
    })
    
    this.loginForm.get('password').valueChanges.subscribe(password => {
      // Do what you want with the password entered in the input field
    })
    })

  }  
}
```

you can read more about reactive forms here, https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Hope this helps